# HTML to Markdown with Java

Tags: java, markdown

is there an easy way to transform HTML into markdown with JAVA?

I am currently using the Java **[MarkdownJ](http://code.google.com/p/markdownj/)** library to transform markdown to html.

```
import com.petebevin.markdown.MarkdownProcessor;
...
public static String getHTML(String markdown) {
    MarkdownProcessor markdown_processor = new MarkdownProcessor();
    return markdown_processor.markdown(markdown);
}

public static String getMarkdown(String html) {
/* TODO Ask stackoverflow */
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There is a great library for JS called [Turndown](https://github.com/domchristie/turndown), you can try it online [here](https://mixmark-io.github.io/turndown/). It works for htmls that the accepted answer errors out.

I needed it for Java (as the question), so I ported it. The library for Java is called [CopyDown](https://github.com/furstenheim/copy-down), it has the same test suite as Turndown and I've tried it with real examples that the accepted answer was throwing errors.

To install with gradle:

```
dependencies {
        compile 'io.github.furstenheim:copy_down:1.0'
}
```

Then to use it:

```java
CopyDown converter = new CopyDown();
String myHtml = "<h1>Some title</h1><div>Some html<p>Another paragraph</p></div>";
String markdown = converter.convert(myHtml);
System.out.println(markdown);
> Some title\n==========\n\nSome html\n\nAnother paragraph\n
```

PS. It has MIT license

Answer (score 7):

There is a Java Library called [flexmark](https://github.com/vsch/flexmark-java) which has such a feature.
Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladsch.flexmark</groupId>
    <artifactId>flexmark-html2md-converter</artifactId>
    <version>0.64.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Using the class `com.vladsch.flexmark.html2md.converter.FlexmarkHtmlConverter` you can convert an HTML String to a Markdown String in one line like this:

```
String md = FlexmarkHtmlConverter.builder().build().convert(html);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, replaced my old code that was using 'Remark'!

Comment: I added the above dependency, but i see error in my bundle, Imported package: Cannot be resolved

Answer (score 3):

I am working on the same issue, and experimenting with a couple different techniques.

The answer above could work. You could use the [jTidy library](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) to do the initial cleanup work and convert from HTML to XHTML. You use the [XSLT stylesheet](http://www.lowerelement.com/Geekery/XML/XHTML-to-Markdown.html) linked above.

Unfortunately there is no library that has a one-stop function to do this in Java. You could try using the Python script [html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) with Jython, but I haven't yet tried this!

Answer (score 2):

if you are using WMD editor and want to get the markdown code on the server side, just use these options before loading the `wmd.js` script:

```
wmd_options = {
        // format sent to the server.  can also be "HTML"
        output: "Markdown",

        // line wrapping length for lists, blockquotes, etc.
        lineLength: 40,

        // toolbar buttons.  Undo and redo get appended automatically.
        buttons: "bold italic | link blockquote code image | ol ul heading hr",

        // option to automatically add WMD to the first textarea found.
        autostart: true
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a Haskell library called [pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc) that can convert between most markup formats.
Although it is not a Java library, it can be [used through its CLI in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496537/8583692).

You can get and [install the latest version from here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/latest). Read the [getting started guides here](https://pandoc.org/getting-started.html).

```java
var command = "pandoc --to=markdown_strict --output=result.md input.html";
var pandoc = new ProcessBuilder()
        .command(command.split(" "))
        .directory(new File(".")) // Working directory
        .start();
pandoc.waitFor();
// The output result.md will be created in the working directory
```

This tool can also be [used in GitHub Actions workflows](https://github.com/pandoc/pandoc-action-example).