# I need to go from HTML to markdown, any suggestion?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, maruku

I'm using Maruku, to convert from Markdown (superset) to HTML, do you know how can I do to convert from HTML to Markdown?

Comment: Use XSLT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59557/html-to-markdown-with-java

Comment: I haven't tried it, and it is likely not as good as one of the dedicated options, but there's also the kramdown gem.  It can take HTML as an input, and it can generate markdown as an output (as well as the reverse).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google found a ruby script called [reverse_markdown](https://github.com/xijo/reverse_markdown). It seems to do what you are looking for.

Comment: I was looking for a native ruby solution to the problem, thanks a lot anyway

Comment: What do you mean by "native ruby"? As far as I can tell the above script is 100% ruby.

Comment: That script falls apart horribly on some fairly basic HTML I fed it. Fed the same HTML to [html2text](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text) and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

try html2markdown http://rubygems.org/gems/html2markdown

And now, I found http://markitdown.medusis.com/ is very useful and quick.