# How to transform HTML to Markdown using Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri, markdown

Is there any way to transform HTML into Markdown text?

- HTML is pretty simple - it's just a div element with several `<p>` elements inside.
- There may be images - I want to preserve them as well.
- Also, there may be several "inline" images like this one: `<img src='images/symbol_minus.gif' width='9' height='3' alt='&minus;' border='0' style='vertical-align:middle;' />` which is just a minus sign - I want to replace them with text.

`Nokogiri::XML::Element#text` is almost something that I want, but it strips off images.

Comment: Please see [this stackoverflow entry][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751622/i-need-to-go-from-html-to-markdown-any-suggestion

Comment: @Konrads, unfortunately, reverse-markdown is dead (github throws 404). Anyway, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Konrads suggested, there is a duplicate entry [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751622/i-need-to-go-from-html-to-markdown-any-suggestion). However, the link which is given in the answer on that entry is broken.

I've googled a bit more and found that some forks survived: https://github.com/tomkrush/reverse-markdown, https://gist.github.com/788039.

If these forks become dead, just google for "reverse markdown". You will definitely find something that is alive and working.