# Convert wiki language to another

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, redmine

Hi 
I used the wiki inside redmine to produce some documentation, during an "evaluation period".
This wiki was hosted somewhere on the net, where i can't acces, meaing acces to the db, not the editable/rendered wiki pages.
Now my ideas are more clear. And i want to host the wiki myself, on a mediawiki instance.

The question is how can i convert the content of the old wiki to the new.

There is no extract button on my redmine wiki.(but i know how to do so with mediawiki)

Since i dont have many pages i can copy the content of the page(meaning the one with wiki mark down language) but i don't want to do the conversion by hand.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandoc: Haven't used it yet, but sounds promising: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/

**EDIT**
Redmine uses the textile markup syntax.
Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839304/convert-textile-markup-to-markdown)

And there is a [mediawiki extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AlternateSyntaxParser) that seems able to read textile

Comment: Actually, pandoc doesn't allow me to convert from textile to wikitext.
And i want to write in wikitext now.
In addition we used a really small portion of the textile capacity, about 6 markup.