# How to convert Wordpress blog posts from Textile 2 to Markdown?

Tags: wordpress, formatting, markdown, textile, pandoc

I switched from Movable Type to Wordpress about a year or two ago. But I have continued to write my posts using Textile 2 formatting (with the help of a WP plugin).

I've been impressed by the way Markdown has proliferated across the web; everywhere from StackOverflow to GitHub and beyond.

So, I'm toying with the idea of converting all my Textile 2-formatted blog posts to Markdown, and I wondered how I might go about doing that.

I saw on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839304/convert-textile-markup-to-markdown) a suggestion to use Pandoc to convert between formats.

Could I use Pandoc to process an SQL export from Wordpress, and then re-import it to WP? What would be the pitfalls?

Or anyone have alternative suggestions on a way to do this?

Comment: View this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23411358/i-am-trying-to-use-textillate-on-a-wordpress-org-website-i-cant-get-it-to-work

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing around with the static blog generators Jekyll and Octopress, which use Markdown as an authoring format. People have written a few tools to export Wordpress to markdown:

https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/blog-migrations

Caveat that I haven't used any of them, but hopefully they help get you started.