# Running Command Line in Java

Tags: java, command-line, runtime.exec

Is there a way to run this command line within a Java application?

```
java -jar map.jar time.rel test.txt debug
```

I can run it with command but I couldn't do it within Java.

Comment: I have tried, Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();Process proc = rt.exec("ping localhost");

Comment: Do you want to launch a VM from within another VM?

Comment: You can try my small library [Jaxec](https://github.com/yegor256/jaxec)

Answer (score 214, accepted):

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("java -jar map.jar time.rel test.txt debug");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: is it normal that when i try to output it to console it only outputs something like this: java.lang.ProcessImpl@6ecec5288

Comment: Use `pr.getInputStream()`. Here is a detailed example: http://www.linglom.com/2007/06/06/how-to-run-command-line-or-execute-external-application-from-java/

Comment: It's useful to check what the process returns with. You can get that with pr.waitFor(). So it looks like this: `int retVal = pr.waitFor()`. So if it's not 0, you can abort / clean up.

Comment: Is there a practical/meaningful difference between `pr.exitValue` and `pr.waitFor()`? Update: I think exitValue will throw an exception if the process has not finished where as waitFor... you know

Comment: nothing it's more java than "Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();"

Comment: This answer is problematic. The called app will block unless you read BOTH stderr and stdout. You will get away with it if only a small amount of output is written but once the buffer is exceeded everything stops.

Answer (score 61):

You can also watch the output like this:

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar map.jar time.rel test.txt debug");

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;

        try {
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();

p.waitFor();
```

And don't forget, if you are running a windows command, you need to put `cmd /c` in front of your command.

EDIT:  And for bonus points, you can also use `ProcessBuilder` to pass input to a program:

```
String[] command = new String[] {
        "choice",
        "/C",
        "YN",
        "/M",
        "\"Press Y if you're cool\""
};
String inputLine = "Y";

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

writer.write(inputLine);
writer.newLine();
writer.close();

String line;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

This will run the windows command `choice /C YN /M "Press Y if you're cool"` and respond with a `Y`.  So, the output will be:

```
Press Y if you're cool [Y,N]?Y
```

Comment: You can also use p.getErrorStream to understand why your command is broken!

Comment: @Craigo: any reference regarding your "cmd /c" statement? thx

Comment: Actually, I think you only need the "cmd /c", if you are wanting to run a windows command, like "copy".  Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: this doesn't print the whole output for me.  executing "ls" prints different amounts of the directory contents each time.  this works best for me: http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016

Answer (score 22):

To avoid the called process to be blocked if it outputs a lot of data on the standard output and/or error, you have to use the solution provided by Craigo. Note also that ProcessBuilder is better than Runtime.getRuntime().exec(). This is for a couple of reasons: it tokenizes better the arguments, and it also takes care of the error standard output (check also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856028/difference-between-processbuilder-and-runtime-exec)).

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "arg1", ...);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
final Process process = builder.start();

// Watch the process
watch(process);
```

I use a new function "watch" to gather this data in a new thread. This thread will finish in the calling process when the called process ends.

```
private static void watch(final Process process) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line = null; 
            try {
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I was actually struggling because I had no stderr.

Answer (score 8):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar map.jar time.rel test.txt debug");
```

Comment: The shortest code is always my favorite.

Answer (score 8):

```
import java.io.*;

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar map.jar time.rel test.txt debug");
```

Consider the following if you run into any further problems, but I'm guessing that the above will work for you:

[Problems with Runtime.exec()](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)

Answer (score 4):

what about

```
public class CmdExec {

public static Scanner s = null;


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("$ ");
    String cmd = s.nextLine();
    final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null; 

            try {
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    p.waitFor();
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar map.jar time.rel test.txt debug");
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the exec command within the Runtime class?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar map.jar time.rel test.txt debug")
```

[Runtime - Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)