# Running a Command Line in Java?

Tags: java, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running Command Line in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java)

Is there a way to run this command line within a Java application?

```
cd "C:\Program Files\myfolder\"&&"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar myjar.jar
```

I can run it with command but i couldnt do it within Java.

Comment: why not, use a Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("$your command")

Comment: Googling the question gives you an enormous amount of examples on how to do it.

Comment: Be careful for platform-dependant commands such as this.  Sometimes there is no choice, but always try to do it in a platform independent method.

Comment: I don't know how to change what to change " to?

Comment: @user1622432 If your asking how to use `"` within `exec`: Just escape it, i.e. use `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("yourcommand") to run command line arguments.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

I would however suggest using a more portable way of referencing that than what you are currently doing.

You can also use Java 6 Compiler API if you want to load classes at runtime rather than call a java program.

http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/