# Is it possible to have persistence.xml in a location other than META-INF?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence.xml

I want to have my persistence.xml in conf folder of my app. How can I tell Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory that it should read it from there?

Comment: If you're using Spring, you can achieve this at least by using `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and specifying the property `persistenceXmlLocation` to point to the file.

Comment: which JPA implementation? DataNucleus JPA allows you to specify where it is stored. Maybe other do too. Not part of the JPA spec obviously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The createEntityManagerFactory methods search for persistence.xml files within the META-INF directory of any CLASSPATH element. 
if your CLASSPATH contains the conf directory, you could place an EntityManagerFactory definition in conf/META-INF/persistence.xml

Comment: It seems I've found a working solution, please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 13):

If you are using EclipseLink you can set the persistence.xml location with the persistence unit property, "eclipselink.persistencexml".

```
properties.put("eclipselink.persistencexml", "/org/acme/acme-persistence.xml");
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("acme", properties);
```

Comment: It it possible to use this solution when persistence.xml is outside jar, for example when persistence.xml path is `/home/foo/downloads/persistence.xml`?

Comment: I have tried different variants and couldn't make it work. From here http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_persistencexml.htm `Currently, this property is used only for the canonical model generator. In the future, it may be used for customizing weaving and application bootstrapping.`

Answer (score 8):

This solution worked for me

```
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new ClassLoader() {
        @Override
        public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {
            if (name.equals("META-INF/persistence.xml")) {
                return Collections.enumeration(Arrays.asList(new File("conf/persistence.xml")
                        .toURI().toURL()));
            }
            return super.getResources(name);
        }
    });
    Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your answer? I dont know enough about spring internals to interpolate where I need to add the above snippet.

Comment: In Spring I would consider http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html#new-in-3.1-jpa-without-xml in the first place

Comment: I would use your solution but it is not working with my configuration: Java 1.6.0_24, EclipseLink 2.3.2. I have an exception "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named XXX". Do you have an idea of why?

Comment: Thank you very much for nice idea. Based on you answer I found and posted answer for EclipseLink 2.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

The ClassLoader may be a URLClassLoader, so try it this way:

```
        final URL alternativePersistenceXmlUrl = new File("conf/persistence.xml").toURI().toURL();

    ClassLoader output;

    ClassLoader current = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    try{

        URLClassLoader parent = (URLClassLoader)current;

        output = new URLClassLoader(parent.getURLs(), parent){

            @Override
            public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {

                if (name.equals("META-INF/persistence.xml")) {

                    return Collections.enumeration(Arrays.asList(alternativePersistenceXmlUrl));
                }

                return super.getResources(name);
            }
        };
    }catch(ClassCastException ignored) {

        output = new ClassLoader() {

            @Override
            public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {

                if (name.equals("META-INF/persistence.xml")) {

                    return Collections.enumeration(Arrays.asList(alternativePersistenceXmlUrl));
                }

                return super.getResources(name);
            }
        };
    }
```

It should work. Works for me under certain test etc conditions.
Please this is a hack and should not be used in production.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is for EclipseLink 2.7.0 and Java 9 and it is modified and detailed version of @Evgeniy Dorofeev answer.

In `org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor` on `line 236`  we see the following code:

```
URL puRootUrl = computePURootURL(descUrl, descriptorPath);
```

This code is used by EclipseLink to compute root url of the persistence.xml path. That's very important because final path will be made by adding `descriptorPath` to `puRootUrl`.

So, let's suppose we have file on `/home/Smith/program/some-folder/persistence.xml`, then we have:

```
Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
ClassLoader previousClassLoader = currentThread.getContextClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new ClassLoader(previousClassLoader) {
    @Override
    public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {
        if (name.equals("some-folder/persistence.xml")) {
            URL url = new File("/home/Smith/program/some-folder/persistence.xml").toURI().toURL();
            return Collections.enumeration(Arrays.asList(url));
        }
        return super.getResources(name);
    }

});
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("eclipselink.persistencexml", "some-folder/persistence.xml");
try {
    entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unit-name", properties);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    logger.error("Error occured creating EMF", ex);
} finally {
    currentThread.setContextClassLoader(previousClassLoader);
}
```

Details:

1. Pay attention that when creating new class loader I pass there previous classloader otherwise it doesn't work.
2. We set property `eclipselink.persistencexml`. If we don't do that then default descriptorPath will be equal to `META-INF/persistence.xml` and we would need to keep our persistence.xml on `/home/Smith/program/META-INF/persistence.xml` to be found.

Comment: I searched and tried different methods for two days, trying to get my persistence.xml out of my distribution jar (so the end user could modify persistence.xml without needing to recompile). Since I am using EcliplseLink 2.5.2, this worked great for me.

Comment: @Tihamer I am really glad that the post helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these ways when the program is starting (at first line of main function):

- Write your persistence.xml to the resources/META-INF/persistence.xml of the jar

  I had problem with this way: [Java write .txt file in resource folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130111/java-write-txt-file-in-resource-folder/36130376)
- Create META-INF folder in the jar directory and put your persistence.xml into it, then execute this command:

  `jar uf $jarName META-INF/persistence.xml`

  This command will replace META-INF/persistence.xml (your file) in the jar

```
    private fun persistence() {
        val fileName = "META-INF/persistence.xml"
        val jarName: String?
        val done = try {
            jarName = javaClass.protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path
            if (File(fileName).exists() && !jarName.isNullOrBlank()
                    && jarName.endsWith(".jar") && File(jarName).exists()) {
                Command().exec("jar uf $jarName META-INF/persistence.xml", timeoutSec = 30)
                true
            } else false
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            false
        }
        if (done) {
            logger.info { "$fileName exist and will be loaded :)" }
        } else {
            logger.info {
                "$fileName not exist in current folder so it will be read from .jar :(" +
                        " you can run: jar uf jarName.jar META-INF/persistence.xml"
            }
        }
    }
```

[Running Command Line in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

A solution by creating tweaked PersistenceUnitDescriptor.

```
import org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.ParsedPersistenceXmlDescriptor;
import org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceXmlParser;
import org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap;
import org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;


public class HibernateEntityManagerFactoryBuilder {

    public static final EntityManagerFactory build(URL xmlUrl) {
        final ParsedPersistenceXmlDescriptor xmlDescriptor = PersistenceXmlParser.locateIndividualPersistenceUnit(xmlUrl);
        final HibernatePersistenceUnitDescriptor hibernateDescriptor = new HibernatePersistenceUnitDescriptor(xmlDescriptor);
        final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder = Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(hibernateDescriptor, Collections.emptyMap(), (ClassLoader) null);
        final EntityManagerFactory factory = builder.build();
        return factory;
    }
    
    
    public static final EntityManagerFactory build(URL xmlUrl, final String name) {
        final ParsedPersistenceXmlDescriptor xmlDescriptor = PersistenceXmlParser.locateNamedPersistenceUnit(xmlUrl, name);
        if(xmlDescriptor == null) throw new RuntimeException("Persistence unit with name '"+name+ "' not found.");
        final HibernatePersistenceUnitDescriptor hibernateDescriptor = new HibernatePersistenceUnitDescriptor(xmlDescriptor);
        final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder = Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(hibernateDescriptor, Collections.emptyMap(), (ClassLoader) null);
        final EntityManagerFactory factory = builder.build();
        return factory;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            final EntityManagerFactory factory = build(new File("D:/ini/persistence.xml").toURI().toURL());
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}


public class HibernatePersistenceUnitDescriptor implements PersistenceUnitDescriptor {

    private final PersistenceUnitDescriptor descriptor;
    
    public HibernatePersistenceUnitDescriptor(PersistenceUnitDescriptor descriptor) {
        this.descriptor = descriptor;
    }

    @Override
    public URL getPersistenceUnitRootUrl() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return descriptor.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public String getProviderClassName() {
        return descriptor.getProviderClassName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseQuotedIdentifiers() {
        return descriptor.isUseQuotedIdentifiers();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isExcludeUnlistedClasses() {
        return descriptor.isExcludeUnlistedClasses();
    }

    @Override
    public PersistenceUnitTransactionType getTransactionType() {
        return descriptor.getTransactionType();
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationMode getValidationMode() {
        return descriptor.getValidationMode();
    }

    @Override
    public SharedCacheMode getSharedCacheMode() {
        return descriptor.getSharedCacheMode();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getManagedClassNames() {
        return descriptor.getManagedClassNames();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getMappingFileNames() {
        return descriptor.getMappingFileNames();
    }

    @Override
    public List<URL> getJarFileUrls() {
        return descriptor.getJarFileUrls();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNonJtaDataSource() {
        return descriptor.getNonJtaDataSource();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getJtaDataSource() {
        return descriptor.getJtaDataSource();
    }

    @Override
    public Properties getProperties() {
        return descriptor.getProperties();
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
        return descriptor.getClassLoader();
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getTempClassLoader() {
        return descriptor.getTempClassLoader();
    }

    @Override
    public void pushClassTransformer(EnhancementContext enhancementContext) {
        descriptor.pushClassTransformer(enhancementContext);
        
    }

}
```