# EclipseLink equivalent to openjpa.properties?

Tags: spring, jpa, eclipselink

Does EclipseLink have something equivalent to openjpa.properties that let's me specify the location of persistence.xml?

Is tweaking the classpath to find persistence.xml the only option for EclipseLink?

FWIW this is a Spring 4. application

TIA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have persistence.xml in a location other than META-INF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717324/is-it-possible-to-have-persistence-xml-in-a-location-other-than-meta-inf)

Comment: Somewhat, that question does lead to the correct answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for a Spring-based app is

```
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
            <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="file:<Path to your persistence.xml>" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```