# JPA Eclipselink/TopLink: how to load persistence.xml from custom folder other than classpath folder ? [Edited]

Tags: java, xml, jpa, eclipselink

I have standalone Java application using JPA. I'm looking to load persistance.xml file from user configured folder. I know JPA vendor checks for meta-inf folder and loads it automatically.

Using this way mentioned below, it is working from any folder path inside the source folder but its not working if I need to load it from other project folders other than source folders. For my application, config folder will be in root folder of project or I might need to get from URL.

```
  properties.put("eclipselink.persistencexml", "config/persistence.xml");
```

Also, i tried with this classloader overwriting mechanism and it didn't work.

```
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new ClassLoader() {
        @Override
        public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        {
            if (name.equals("META-INF/persistence.xml")) {
                return Collections.enumeration(Arrays.asList(new File("/config/persistence.xml").toURI().toURL()));
            }
            return super.getResources(name);
        }
        });
```

I will need to load persistance.xml manually from folder other than folder from source where classloader is scanning for classes. Does anybody know how to do it with eclipselink/toplink JPA in non-applicaiton server related environments?

```
  Map properties = new HashMap();
  //properities
  properties.put("eclipselink.************", "*****"); 



  javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory emf_myDB=javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(DB_PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME, properties);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717324/is-it-possible-to-have-persistence-xml-in-a-location-other-than-meta-inf

Comment: comething like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717324/is-it-possible-to-have-persistence-xml-in-a-location-other-than-meta-inf see last post.

Answer (score 3):

**It's not possible**, at least not without modifying classloader environment.

**Reason:**

Under the hood, EclipseLink solely uses `ClassLoader.getResources()` to get the contents of the `persistence.xml`.
With this method it's **impossible** to reach resources **outside classloader scope** (which is the classpath in many classloader implementations).

The only thing you could theoretically do is to use a custom classloader which behaves differently, something like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13985199/324152) (even if it didn't worked for you).
However, I'd consider that as a hack in most cases and hence I would not use it in an enterprise application.

***The more interesting question is why you want to do this.***
 A persistence unit is always coupled to a specific set of entity classes, hence there is no reason why a user would need to specify another persistence.xml (location).
If the user should be able to set custom persistence unit properties - use a configuration mechanism of your choice and pass the user customized properties as a `Map` during `EntityManagerFactory` creation.

Comment: Thanks, I already evaluated that classloader mechanism before posting here but it's failing to override the property "META-INF/persistence.xml" with given folder path out side of classloader scope for some reason. May be I need to look into URLclassloader. I have a custom application framework which has in built mechanism to expose a parameter to load the property driven configuration file from its work space which is visible to admin users.

Comment: So that they can update DB connectivity parameters  in different hosts to connect from java based applications (JPA driven application in this case) unlike updating with unjaring and jaring.