# Java write .txt file in resource folder

Tags: java

I am trying to write a .txt file in a resource folder but it doesn't write anything. I am able to read the same .txt file by doing:

```
Scanner scanner = null;
InputStream IS = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/File/My FileH");
scanner = new Scanner(IS);
```

But when it comes to write, I have tried doing:

```
PrintWriter writer =  new PrintWriter(
    new File(this.getClass().getResource("/File/My FileH").getFile()));
writer.println("hello");
writer.close();
```

Any suggestions on how to write in that folder?

Comment: Try `PrintWriter writer =  new PrintWriter(
        new File(this.getClass().getResource("/File/My FileH").getPath()));` to get the writer.

Comment: Resources are not files, and their locations are folders in JAR files, not directories in the file system. You need to rethink your requirement.

Comment: @bigdestroyer It still doesn't write with that change.

Comment: @EJP What would you suggest me to do this file writing then?

Comment: what is that file for?

Comment: @Rhayene It is for storing a ECC private key.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't write something in to a resource, assume that you packed your resource as a jar. Jar is only `read only`. You can't update that. Either you can extract the `jar` and edit the contents.

You can try [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html) as an alternative

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. I will try to find another way to do this.

Comment: We can create a folder in current directory for write and read access

Comment: @Ram Sure, we can write in any location in system with write access. But not inside a jar resource folder.