# How can I write to a file which shall be bundled with my application, if I cannot write into a file in resources folder (Eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, file

My application shall be packaged (shall be a jar distributed with) a file, which initially contains data. Then application  appends this file. I attached this file as a resource (I created a resource folder in elipse and made it a source folder), but now I understand it is read-only! There was [such question in [SO].](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130111/java-write-txt-file-in-resource-folder)

So how can I distribute a file with my application and append this file as my application works? What is a best way for that? This is a plain txt file.

Comment: just add the jar and external file into a zip.

Comment: Thank you! But how shall I code my access to that file? Relative to what? To directory where jar is run from? I don't want to instruct the user "Please put my file.txt in c:/MyAppName/Resource folder, and don't forget to create this folder..."

Comment: pass in a system property to java with the path to the file

Comment: Might also be able to use environment vars like %appdata% on windows maps to C:\Users\USERSNAME\AppData\Roaming