# disribution package of my app will not contain /src folder

Tags: java, spring, resources, classpath, production

I'm working on my localhost on spring boot app, where I use references of some files.
For example :

> "src/main/resources/myZip.zip"

As I know, in production distribution package of this app will not contain /src folder.

Can someone please tell me another way how can I get different references of this files for producton?

Also can someone suggest how can I create new file in resources?

I am using

> Files.write(Path.of("src/main/resources/newFile.zip), fileContent,
> StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

to add new file, but I'm interested in how to create new file without

> "src/main/resources"

Comment: Kindly dont use  `src/main/resources` in your paths..even for DEV/Test purposes.  Please look into `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("folderDirectlyInsideResources/otherPackages/file.txt");` if you want an InputStream, or `getResource()` if you wanted a URL

Comment: Thank you. 
Changed with getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myZip.zip").
If you know, I also use Files.readAllLines(Path.of("myZip.zip"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
this Path.of needs String and not URL, how can I handle this?

Comment: You cant use Paths.of, do `Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("directoryUnderResources/file.txt").toURI());` instead and that gives you a PATH

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you also please tell me last thing?, how can I create new file in resources? I was using Files.write(Path.of("src/main/resources/newFile.zip), fileContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); but now its not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130111/java-write-txt-file-in-resource-folder     You shouldnt.  The idea is to create a file in your PC where the jar runs.  You cant modify the contents of src/main/resources of the jar file itself..