# Building a jekyll site from java

Tags: java, gwt, jekyll

I have a java (GWT) web app with products, where users can add products and set their description and price etc.

I am thinking about the following flow:
whenever a product is updated, run a jekyll build and deploy.

this way the eventual site with all the products will be completely static (with some extra javascript to handle shoppingcart etc), and thus very fast indeed.

Is there a way to call 'jekyll build' from java servlet? I don't have much experience with this... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.

Just run the command line from Java [as explained here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java)

```
jekyll build --source <source> --destination <destination>
```

Of course you might be calling it from a RPC instead of a plain Java servlet.