# Using Scala's Runtime

Tags: scala, runtime

I `cd`'d into a directory containing two Scala classes.

```
C:\Kevin\Workspace\>dir

09/08/2013  09:13 PM               331 Max.scala
09/08/2013  09:13 PM               459 Test.scala
               2 File(s)            790 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  72,008,863,744 bytes free
```

Then, I opened up REPL:

```
C:\Kevin\Workspace\>scala

Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import java.lang.Runtime
import java.lang.Runtime

scala> val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime
runtime: Runtime = java.lang.Runtime@55dae09c
```

Then (with this [post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java) help) I tried to compile my *.scala files via `scalac` as an argument to `Runtime#exec`, but it failed.

```
scala> runtime.exec("scalac Max.scala Test.scala")
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "scalac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specifie
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
        at .<init>(<console>:12)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
```

How can I do the above in Scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not so much a Scala thing as it is a Windows thing, which I infer from your first code block.

On my Mac, I find this:

```
scala> Runtime.getRuntime.exec("scalac")
res2: Process = java.lang.UNIXProcess@24c63dac
```

On Windows, try providing the fully qualified path to `scalac`. If that doesn't work, consider using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks, Vidya. Using the fully qualified path/absolute path to `scalac.bat` worked. I ran `scalac MyFile.scala`, but I didn't see `MyFile.class` output. Any idea why?