# How do you pipe the output of one file to input of another in Java?

Tags: java, io, stdout, stdin, piping

Can someone show me code of something simple that pipes the output from one java file to the input of another in Java?

Say you have a file that is called `hello.java` that just simply outputs "hello". How would I pipe this output from the command line into another Java program called `addWorld.java` that simply adds "world" to the end of the input from `hello.java` and then outputs "hello world" on the console screen?

I'm sure it is very simple, but I've looked around and I still don't understand how to do it. I've tried to make an example that is as simple as possible so there isn't a lot of code written so I can just understand what to do in a general case. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using unix? It's easy then you can use < for input and > for output

Comment: No, using the command prompt on Windows. I keep seeing to use | but that keeps not working for me

Comment: Ahh sorry. I really suck with windows. GL

Comment: Check out my answer. It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to start the second java program using run time probably and add the output for the first command as a parameter for running the second, as from what I've tried Windows does not like piping into other programs.

Quick how-to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496537/3342157

Information on Runtime: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, in the command line, this is done with the redirection operator (`>`)

It is done as so:

```
java hello > java addWorld
```

This would take the `stdout` of hello.java (anything printed using `System.out`) into the `stdin` of addWorld.java as a command line argument (the `args` part of `public static void main(String[] args)`)

EDIT:
The pipe character (`|`) filters the `stdout` of the program through a program. If `sort` sorts a program alphabetically based on its `stdin`, typing this:

```
simon-answers.txt | sort > simon-answers-sorted.txt
```

into a windows command prompt would take the lines in `simon-answers.txt` ("Simon says" commands) and pipe (`|`) them through `sort` and then redirect (`>`) them to the text file `simon-answers-sorted.txt`