# passing input file in java through command line

Tags: java, command-line

```
 FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
```

This is above code to get the input file , i want a input file to give from command line

i.e.
pseudo command line code

```
java  filename giveinputfile("textfile.txt")
```

What change i modify in my java code and command line(windows) to make this work

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Command Line in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You use the `String[] args` in your main method,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String fileName = "textfile.txt";
  if (args.length > 0) { 
    fileName = args[0];
  }
  System.out.println("fileName: " + fileName);
}
```

Then you run your program with

```
java myProgram MY_FILE
```

or

```
java myProgram
```

With the code above the first command would use "MY_FILE" and the second would use the default "textfile.txt".