# Triggering commands to Terminal by using java code

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

Can anyone suggest me that how to trigger the commands like cd,ls by using java with code.

Comment: With a little effort you would have found something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java

Comment: Note: running 'cd' from Java will have no effect, as the command is executed in a new process.

Comment: There should be a _Let me Google that for you_ button beside the _add a comment_ button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is  a simple sceranio like this. i run my program in D: and i want to go to a folder in C:\Users\erdemk\Desktop\directory and run a dir command on it. you can use this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "c: && cd \"C:\\Users\\erdemk\\Desktop\\directory\" && dir");
  builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
  Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```