# How can sent the date in a datepicker appium (Android API 19, version 1.2.4.1)

Tags: java, android, datepicker, appium

I have a problem in setting the date from a date picker in Appium. I'm trying to set the date by sending keys in the fields in this way:

```
List<WebElement> pick = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));           

        pick.get(0).sendKeys("21");
        pick.get(1).sendKeys("Mar");
        pick.get(2).sendKeys("1989");
```

This works fine in previous versions of API but since I'm testing in a different device now appium seems not to finding my elements correctly. Here is a photo from the inspector window that shows that I'm using the correct class to find the fields.[image]

Any ideas?Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's the problem because some information is missing, but maybe try using `swipe` instead of `sendKeys`, it doesn't look like a sendKeys field.

Anyway I can recommend a workaround that I'm using when I need to change the date while testing, you can use the following adb command:

> adb shell date -s YYYYMMdd.HHmmss

It's much faster and reliable,
hope this helps.

Comment: Make sure you have adb installed on your PC and usb debugging enabled on your device and just run the command via command line, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java) will help you.

Comment: But how does that help me automate a test? Basically every time that I will have to run my test I will have to be sending a date while the test will be running. Is there any way to send this adb command programmatically?

Comment: Yeah, just run in Java:
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell date -s YYYYMMdd.HHmmss");`

Answer (score 0):

Perform action with xpath

```
// Select month name in datepicker
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']")).sendKeys("Jan");

// Select day in datepicker
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='1']")).sendKeys("24");

// Select year in datepicker
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='2']")).sendKeys("1987");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform This way

```
    List<WebElement> textFieldsList = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText")); 
    int size = textFieldsList.size();
    textFieldsList.get(0).sendKeys("test");
    textFieldsList.get(1).sendKeys("test");
    textFieldsList.get(2).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this as shown below in the appium-java client as none of the above worked for me:

Android emulator API level: 28

Android emulator version: 9

Appium java client version: 5.0.4

`currentMonthElement` in the code below is the `WebElement` that represents the month field in the datepicker. You can use find by xpath or whichever way you like to find this element using `driver.findElement`. The below code can be reused to enter value for date and year elements. In the place of `currentMonthElement` variable, please pass the date and year elements.

```
touchAction.longPress(LongPressOptions.longPressOptions().withElement(ElementOption.element(currentMonthElement))).release().perform();
driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
String monthstr = "Aug";
while(!currentMonthElement.getText().equals(monthstr)){
    driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys("Aug");
}
//click on ok button after setting the date, month & year

driver.findElement(By.id("button1")).click();
```