# Launch multiple java applications from one java application

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, program-entry-point, launcher

Let's say that I have Client class with a main method that does something (maybe connecting to class Server).

Is there  a way to create a class (let's say ClientLauncher) that launch n clients (n passed as a parameter) as different java applications?

Note that, I do not want these clients to be different threads inside one application. I want to obtain the same effect that I would get by pressing the run button in Eclipse several times (launching different main methods).

Comment: It's possible, though I would recommend doing that using shell/batch script rather than writing a program.

Comment: You can run additional programs using the command line. This can be called from within Java. Is that along the lines you're thinking?

Comment: So you want to run a jvm per client? You'll need to use the Runtime to launch separate processes. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java

Comment: [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) allows to launch new process. You could launch a `java myProgram` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't want to run clients using threads,
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` can invoke extarnal jars within a class

```
Process run= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar jarpath_here");
```

If you put this in loop you'd have multiple processes.

Comment: Rather use the more advanced `ProcessBuilder` class, but this is the gist of it.