# How to do real time command line interaction in Java?

Tags: java, command-line

I know how to invoke command line in Java like this

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("dir && c: && dir"); // also can run multiple command with &&
```

then I can print its response while getting its `InputStream` this is working fine I found very good examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java). I can also run multiple commands one after another while putting `&&` in between commands. But once I invoked `rt.exec()` after that i cannot run any other command meaning i lose control from command line meaning only i can print `InputStream`.

My problem is that I want to run command and after analyzing its response i want to write next command dynamically according to previous command response.

Note: I can run multiple commands with `&&` but its only  when i know what will happen after one command and while assuming I run next command like we run in `Real Command Line Window`?

Comment: The following might interest you (Java 9's REPL): http://www.jclarity.com/2015/04/15/java-9-repl-getting-started-guide/

Comment: I am working in Java7.

Comment: So upgrade... :) And seriously, you know that Java 7 is [no longer supported](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml), right ?

Comment: @alfasin I'm having customers with Java 5...updating is not the answer in any environment :-/. I wish it could be that easy...

Comment: @VWeber when you publish an API to your customer that's a different case than trying to implement a REPL when it already exists ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look with [Apache CLI framework](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)