# How can I merge .webm (Audio) file and a .mp4 (Video) file using java?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I have two files one is a .webm audio file and the other one is a .mp4 video file
Is there a way to combine these two files together using java?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This could be achieved by using `ffmpeg` `C` library via `JNI` or via executing `ffmpeg` command line binaries.

Here are the steps for command line execution:

1. Download FFmpeg: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html
   . You Can download the source from the [repository](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/) and build them as per your machine architecture.
2. Extract downloaded file to specific folder, say c:\ffmpeffolder
   Using cmd move to specific folder c:\ffmpeffolder\bin
3. Run following command: `$ ffmpeg -i audioInput.webm -i videoInput.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy outputFile.avi`

Command line Execution from Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496537/2900034

This is it. outputFile.avi will be the resulting file.

Or if you want to work around ffmpeg C libraries

Here are some good starts.

1. [JNI](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html).
2. [ffmpeg api example](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/tree/master/doc/examples).