# Writing additional video data into a temporary file from DataBuffer not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, temporary-files

I have two video files, which I'm trying to merge into one temporary file. But I always end up having a file which contains only the longer first file "pip.webm". If I write to `position: 0` instead of `channel.size()` it will obviously override the existing data.

*pip.webm* 
Duration: 5:00 Minutes

*transparent_short.webm*
Duration: 10 Seconds

**What I did so far:**

1. At start, read pip.webm into a DataBuffer.
2. Call `createPipFile()` to create an temporary file, an AsynchroniousFileChannel, and writing the DataBuffer into the temporary file.
3. Calling `override()` to read "transparent_short.webm" into a second Databuffer and then writing the second `DataBuffer` into the same teporary file as before.

I tried using `StandardOpenOperation.APPEND` for the channel, but this will throw an `APPEND not allowed` Error.

Another approach would be, to first merge both DataBuffers into one and then writing to the file at `position: 0`. But I couldn't figure out how to merge the DataBuffers or how to add data to an DataBuffer which already contains data. Maybe using `DataBufferUtils.join()` but I didn't get how to do that.

### Code

**OverrideOverlayVideo.java**

```
@Component
public class OverrideOverlayVideo {

  private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(OverrideOverlayVideo.class);

  final static Path sourceFile = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\x\\pip.webm");
  final static int DATABUFFERSIZE = 256*64;
  final static DataBufferFactory dbf = new DefaultDataBufferFactory();
  static Flux<DataBuffer> dataBuffer = DataBufferUtils.read(sourceFile, dbf, DATABUFFERSIZE);

  public static String newClipPath2;
  public LinkedList<String> clipPathList = new LinkedList<>();

  public String createPipFile() {
    try {
      Path targetFolder = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\x\\pip");
      Path newClipPath = Files.createTempFile(targetFolder,"pip" , ".webm");

      String newClipPath2 = newClipPath.normalize().toString();
      
      clipPathList.add(0, newClipPath2);

      AsynchronousFileChannel channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(newClipPath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
     
      DataBufferUtils.write(dataBuffer, channel, 0)
                     .subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer()); 
     
      return newClipPath2;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return newClipPath2;
  }

  public Mono<Void> override() {
    Path pathToInsertionClip = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("C:\\x\\pip\\transparent_short.webm");
    Flux<DataBuffer> databufferNewClip = DataBufferUtils.read(pathToInsertionClip, dbf, DATABUFFERSIZE);
    Path newClipPath2 = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(clipPathList.get(0));

    try {
     AsynchronousFileChannel channel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(newClipPath2, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
     
     DataBufferUtils.write(databufferNewClip, channel, channel.size())
                    .subscribe(DataBufferUtils.releaseConsumer());
    
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return Mono.empty();
                                        
  }

}
```

**SendVideoInController.java**

```
@RestController
public class SendVideoInController {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(SendVideoInController.class);
    private final OverrideOverlayVideo overrideOverlayVideo;

    public SendVideoInController(OverrideOverlayVideo overrideOverlayVideo) {
        this.overrideOverlayVideo = overrideOverlayVideo;
    }
    
    @GetMapping(value = "send/sendVideo")
    private Mono<Void> sendVideoIn() {
        log.info("Video received");
        return overrideOverlayVideo.override();
    }
}
```

Comment: [catch (Exception e) {}](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/94-ignoring-exceptions-is-dangerous)

Comment: @g00se I kept the code as short as possible

Comment: I don't know this api, so can't comment. What I can say is that generally speaking, there are few file formats where you can concatenate files successfully with a simple buffer copy owing to the metadata in each applying *only* to each. Whether that's what's happening, I don't know

Comment: @g00se seems to be right, you can't just concat WebM files byte by byte. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939131/how-can-i-merge-webm-audio-file-and-a-mp4-video-file-using-java) post. It is not exactly what you're looking for, but you'll get an idea which tools do you need.

Comment: @0x1C1B Oh i see. Makes sense. I just hoped it would work, because it is working if you receive payloads with chunked data which is then written into a databuffer which then is beeing wirtten to the file after each chunk, but those chunks probably got the right metadata to be treated as a whole. Fortunately using FFMPEG isn't much of a problem. Thanks guys :)