# Java check if program is installed on windows

Tags: java, windows, zip

Is there a way to check if a specific program is installed on Windows using Java?

I'm trying to develop a Java program that automatically creates zip archives by using the code line command from 7-Zip.

So, I would like to check in Java if on my windows OS '7-Zip' is already installed. No check for running apps or if OS is Windows or Linux. I want to get a bool (true/false) if '7-Zip' is installed on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The unix-like solution would be to simply try to run the program with `--version` flag (on windows probably the `/?` or - like in the 7zip case - without any at all) and check whether it fails, or what the return code will be.

Something like:

```
public boolean is7zipInstalled() {
    try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("7zip.exe");
            int code = process.waitFor();
            return code == 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The library Apache Commons has a class called `SystemUtils` - full documentation is available at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/SystemUtils.html.

In this library you have the following `static boolean` properties at your disposal:

```
SystemUtils.IS_OS_LINUX
SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand me :)
I don't want to check, if this is windows, I want to check if ON MY WINDOWS '7-Zip' is installed

Answer (score -1):

I know this is quite an old question but if someone still wants the answer for Windows, I prefer using the command line instead of deprecated old libraries

Example in Powershell:

```
(gp HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*).DisplayName -Contains "Android Studio"
```

You will get `True` or `False` as output

**This is only works for Windows**

Comment: This is the easiest solution for now, if you have a better way feel free to share your opinion as an answer so everyone can benefit from your answers

Comment: It's true it in Powershell command but it can be executed in Java code, even if it's not the best, if you have better please feel free to share it

Comment: A quick search on google will do. the docs also cover all of this very easily, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496537/18519412

Comment: I don't see a better answer here, If there is then just use it if you don't want to share anything then I don't see your point. if my solution is very far away from perfect and it 
doesn't fit your needs then feel free to use another one. just mark the question as unhelpful and I see you already did.