# How do I get and run a jar file within a Java program?

Tags: java, jar, jinternalframe

I'm creating an operating system-like program in java and have run into a little trouble. I want the user to be able to run jar files of their choice in it, but I don't really know how though.

Basically, it will work like this:

1. The user opens a program in the OS called "Import Jar".
2. The user clicks "browse", then a JFileChooser pops up.
3. After the user specified a file, they click "Finish".
4. The Jar starts up in a JInternalFrame.

Comment: Take a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java) Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Runtime.exec(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) method for that.

For example:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("java -jar yourJar.jar");
```

Does start your `jar` within a running Java program. In your case you have to ensure that the jar `yourJar.jar` starts in a `JInternalFrame`.

Comment: How would I start it in a the Internal Frame though?

Comment: You have to ensure, If you run the jar seperately on your own (by invoking "java -jar yourJar.jar" in -for example- Windows cmd) that it starts a for example JFrame.