# Sending a command line command from JButton?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I would like to build something like the apache xampp control panel. I would like to create my own control panel that start/stops my server.

I am using Eclipse GUI Builder and I tried to search online for help regarding this but couldn't find anything. Can anyone provide some help to me?

For example, usually when I start my server I would go to command prompt, go to the directory and type run.bat. When stopping the server, I would have to do ctrl + c.

How do I achieve this by clicking a JButton (Start server) and another JButton (Stop server)?

There is nothing much on my coding since it is default Eclipse Swing GUI generated codes.

Comment: possible solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java

Comment: ProcessBulder would be the preferred solution, any other is asking for a lot of boil plating and potential issues

Comment: So if I have a dynamic directory for run.bat, can I make a jtextfield for user to enter the directory where run.bat exist and then listen to the textfield? After which running run.bat from that text field directory after clicking the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your OS for the command int the runtime.exec method but in a normal case you can try this:

```
    JButton startServer = new JButton();
    startServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                // Here exec your bat file
                runtime.exec("Path_To_Your_Bat_File");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    JButton stopServer = new JButton();
    stopServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                //Here get your process id and kill it
                runtime.exec("Get_Process & Kill");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! Am I able to listen to a text field so that the path can be dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("COMMAND_HERE");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html