# How to execute a jar file trough java on a different directory

Tags: java, directory, executable-jar

I'm trying to get my java program to execute a jar file which is located on a USB-drive, and I got the code to find the specific file and it's path already but I can't find anything online about how to run said file.

Can anyone help me or direct me to where I can find how to do this?

To clarify, this is not asking how to open a jar file from the cmd, this is asking how to open a jar file from a different java application. This is somewhat related to: [how to run a jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238145/how-to-run-a-jar-file) and [running command line in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java) as it combines both of them.

Comment: Duplicate of "[How to run a JAR file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1238145/5221149)" and "[Running Command Line in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8496494/5221149)".

Comment: This first one did not help me, the second one did. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute `java -jar <fully qualified path for your jar on usb>` from your java program by using `Runtime` or `ProcessBuilder` class.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise I needed to use runtime, nor have I ever worked with it (still fairly new to java).

Comment: your welcome. Glad that helped you :)