# Sikuli X run application with given path

Tags: java, sikuli, sikuli-script

Is there a way to run an application from java code when using sikuliX? 
For example autoIt had a method

```
Run("C:\Folder\YourFavouriteExecutionFile.exe");
```

I am looking something like this in Sikuli X. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running SikuliX from its API you are just running Java code, so it might be useful to take a look in the question linked below.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8496537/3586361

Comment: This does not answer my question