# How do I open any installed software in my pc using a java program?

Tags: java

I want to open installed softwares in my pc using a java program. For Example- If I want to open Microsoft Outlook using java program, how would I do it? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: [Running Command Line in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Java ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to launch any program.

Example from [this site](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/processbuilder/java-lang-processbuilder-example/)

```
package com.javacodegeeks.process;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ProcessBuilderExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
            IOException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "This is ProcessBuilder Example from JCG");
        System.out.println("Run echo command");
        Process process = pb.start();
        int errCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Echo command executed, any errors? " + (errCode == 0 ? "No" : "Yes"));
        System.out.println("Echo Output:\n" + output(process.getInputStream()));    
    }

    private static String output(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```