# How to embed an external exe into another jar using java

Tags: java, external, executable

I am trying to create a tool using java where I want to embed and execute external third party exe and get the output from it in my tool that I am creating.

My constraint is that I cannot let the user get hold of this embedded exe on the system that I am running the tool on, so it must be dynamically deployed, executed and receive output from it and then deleted before the user exits the tool.
My tool can be either a jar or an exe.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, there is no way to do it, for two reasons:  One, a Java application is an archive which any user can examine.  Two, you will have to write your executable to a separate file in order to execute it, and the user will be able to copy it when you do.

Comment: The `Runtime` class can start a subprocess, and the returned `Process` object from `Runtime#exec(String)`, can create a in-/output stream to the subprocess. Not sure how you'd achieve the "covertness" of the file's existence, it's just... not plausible, unless it's deployed on a separate system, and then data is tunneled through e.g. a socket.

Answer (score 0):

JAR is usual compressed file, you can put anything in it. Including exe files. You can execute command line commands via Java like this:

[Running Command Line in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java).

So in theory you can extract the exe from your JAR and execute it via command line, read the command line output and continue based on this. About a guarantee that user will not just extract the EXE manually himself - There are no means of doing this in a reliable way. So if your intention is to wrap some other program and limit it's functionality with your wrapper then this is not the way to do it.