# Running hadoop command from Java File

Tags: java, hadoop

How to run below hadoop command from java file :

hadoop jar '/home/ashish/Desktop/HADOOP_Basics/WordCount_Program/wordcount.jar' WordCount /WordCountTutorial/Input /WordCountTutorial/Output

Please explain in detail .

I am getting the below error while executing it through :
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("hadoop jar '/home/ashish/Desktop/HADOOP_Basics/WordCount_Program/wordcount.jar' WordCount /WordCountTutorial/Input1 /WordCountTutorial/Output");

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hadoop": error=2, No such file or directory

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Command Line in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496494/running-command-line-in-java)

Comment: This question is diffrent with other one. Here i am asking for hadoop command not a normal java command. Please check  @cricket_007

Comment: I feel like you didn't read the other answers, and only the accecpted one. `rt.exec` is correct, **but**, you need `hadoop` available on your OS's path, which is externally managed from Java... You can fix it with `/full/path/to/hadoop jar ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you give full path to hadoop then it will run.
eg command :

```
/home/project/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -ls /
```